# Using Product Tag In Checkout Tag

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, tags

Is there some sort of way in Expresso-Store that I am able to use the `{exp:store:product}` tag inside of the `{exp:store:checkout}` tag without generating a 'product form' inside of the 'checkout form'? I need to use the {total_stock} tag from `{exp:store:product}`.

I tried to use `{exp:store:product}` inside of `{exp:store:checkout}`, but then my submit button to go to the next checkout step did not respond at all and I think this might have been because there were two forms on the page?

I have this code within my `{exp:store:checkout}` tag:

```
{if total_stock > 0}
    <select name="qty">{exp:lb_cart:get_cart_stock t_stock="{total_stock}" item_qty="{item_qty}"}</select>
{if:else}
    <p>Out Of Stock ({item_qty}). Item will be removed from the cart.</p>
{/if}
```

Is it possible to user the `{total_stock}` referencing `{exp:store:product}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `disable_form="yes"` to the `{exp:store:product}` tag to disable the creation of the form. ([Docs.](https://exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#disable_form_yes))